# .htaccess hidden parameter before page name

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite urls like:

```
http://www.domain.com/contact?language=en
http://www.domain.com/?language=en
```

to:

```
http://www.domain.com/en/contact
http://www.domain.com/en/
```

using:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]+)/?$ $2/index.php?language=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I'm not sure why this isnt working!?

**EDIT**

I changed the rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ $2/?language=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Which does not give errors with the URL's like the old rule above it. However, it does not goto the directory specified

```
http://www.domain.com/en/contact <- stays at the / (root)
```

Comment: I don't see `index.php` in your original urls; PS: for the second url the part you must replace `[^/]+` with `[^/]*` PPS: "isn't working" - is not a good way to explain the issue you're experiencing

Comment: I fixed is as "RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ $2/?language=$1 [QSA,L]" it gives me the language GET but it does not switch the page. I think it is treating contact as a variable too but I need it to route to /contact

Comment: I cannot guess, please update the question with new details: new regexp, and all urls

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(en|fr|de|nl)/(.*)$ /$2?language=$1 [QSA,L]
```